Blue "USB 3.0" extension cable has "USB 2.0" printed on the cable itself; which USB is it truly?
Elaboration: recently bought 4 blue "USB 3.0" extension cables - the cable itself was blue, the ports are too, yet upon reading the text printed on each cable, it says: "USB 2.0 Cable". There are 9 pins inside the male plugs and female ports, hence I ask: do I assume it's USB 3.0 and consider the text a typo, or is there more to it than meets the eye?

Do you have any way of checking if it performs as a USB 3.0 cable? For example, you might have a USB drive which transfers data at more than 30 MB/s when it's plugged in directly—if it only works at 30 MB/s (or less) then the cable probably only has the wires for USB 2.0.

Try https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html and plug a known-good USB3 flash drive behind the extender. The tool will show the speed of connection.
